# Error JSON parsing data android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have a data parsing problem, in my logcat i've found this error:

```
Error parsing dataorg.json.JSONException: No value for nome
```

This is my parser code:

```
try {
           JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String aa = json_data.getString("nome");
                Log.i("log_tag", "JSON:" + aa);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
             {
            Log.e("log_tag_parsing", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());
             }
```

Obviously the field name exist in my json result page.
For clarity i will post also my json.

```
[
    {
        "punti": {
            "_id": {
                "$id": "551fb585ecba12c819000032"
            },
            "nome": "Google",
            "loc": [
                -122.083983,
                37.422969
            ],
            "icona": 1,
            "istituzione_id": {
                "$id": "551fb556ecba12c819000031"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Someone can help me? i tried in many ways but i can't reach solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract `"nome"` from the `"punti"` object: `json_data.getJSONObject("punti")`

```
try {
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject punti = json_data.getJSONObject("punti");
        String aa = punti.getString("nome");
        Log.i("log_tag", "JSON:" + aa);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("log_tag_parsing", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "nome" field is inside the "punti" JSONObject. Your code must be :

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject json_punti = json_data.getJSONObject("punti");
                String aa = json_punti .getString("nome");
                Log.i("log_tag", "JSON:" + aa);
            }
```